# Mathematics SE Birthday Celebration?

Tags: discussion, celebration

Did you know Mathematics SE’s birthday graduation was on **October 25th**? Congratulations!

I don't know if this community would be interested in something like this, but how about a contest or some other fun activity to stir things up a little? After a year of great Q&A, **we'd like the opportunity to "give back" for everyone's hard work.**

Anniversary events are a great way to spark some interest in the extracurricular activity in your site (more meta participation). An “anniversary event" can be just about anything. Take a look at [**Super User’s 2nd Birthday Super Contest**](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) for inspiration. It doesn’t have to be a contest. Dream up whatever *you* feel the community will find interesting, and go for it.

Start a meta post or chat event to work out the details. Rally support for your event and bring it to our attention (community@stackexchange.com). We're really interested in community-led initiatives, so let’s just say, if you can work out the details, we’re very motivated to say “go for it!”

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624/happy-first-birthday-m-se)

Comment: Maybe the Grand Prize could be a weekend with Arturu Magidin! Of course, he will probably win... (This, in the spirit of some recent hero worship that has since been deleted from MSE)